# Creating a bash-like Terminal GUI

Tags: unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I asked this before and didn't get an answer. I would like to create a linux-like scene for my game. This means that it should look like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Linux_command-line._Bash._GNOME_Terminal._screenshot.png . Right now I have the two window approach(like common text based games) but i cant mimic the behavior in linux.

Comment: What do you mean by "the two window approach" and how does it fail on Linux?

Comment: http://imgur.com/9ljwNV0 This is what I meant.